# Are these line codes the same?

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I want to know if these two scripts do the same thing:

```
parseInt(num)?num=parseInt(num):num=str.length
```

and

```
num=parseInt(num)||str.length;
```

And in case they are not, I need to know what the second do.

Comment: and on a side note, any one knows why compilers don't turn the first one to `num=parseInt(num)?parseInt(num):str.length`? edit: or to the second one (since you guys say it is the same)?

Comment: They are not that advanced. Simple. And - why would they?

Comment: @RokKralj "why would they?", their job is to make the code as short as possible without changing the output, and one is like 13 characters shorter

Comment: Ah, good. Then, first part of the answer :) Accounting all such cases and permutations of the code, that is really no simple thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are same with later (*short circuit evaluation*) being terse and a beauty of JS (or other languages that support it):

```
num = parseInt(num) || str.length;
```

Both in turn are short-cut of this:

```
if (parseInt(num)){
   num = parseInt(num);
}
else {
   num = str.length;
}
```

**Good Practices:**

- Don't foget `var` keyword before `num` variable otherwise it goes into **global** scope.
- Always specify a base to `parseInt` eg `parseInt(num, 10)` unless otherwise needed

---

**Readings:**

- [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php)
- [Ternary Operator](http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-javascript/)

Comment: I did not downvote, but this is not 100% correct. The first one is like the second example you posted. The second one is `num = parseInt(num); if(!num) num = str.length;`, calling `parseInt` only once.

Comment: @copy: That's what I meant to say OP should go with second example, that is sign of bad code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do (but the second is very slightly more efficient as it doesn't have to run `parseInt` twice).

Answer (score 1):

yes, they are equal. This is also the same:

```
num = parseInt(num)?parseInt(num):str.length
```